# Laravel check more then one parameter on eloquant-relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have Three Table like below structure.

Table- AccountService

```
id | service_id| account_id|
----------------------------
 1 | 1         | 8181      |
 2 | 2         | 8181      |
 3 | 3         | 8181      |
 4 | 5         | 8181      |
```

Table :- Services

```
 id | Name |
------------
 1 | A     |   
 2 | B     | 
 3 | C     | 
 4 | D     |
```

Table :- CompletedService

```
 id | service_id | account_id
------------------------------
 1 | 1           | 8181  
 2 | 1           | 8182
 3 | 1           | 8181
 4 | 2           | 8181
```

Now MY relation Query is below.

```
 $acc = AccountService::with(['service' => function($q) {

                    }])->with(['completedServiceRest' => function($q) {

                    }])->where('account_id', $account_id)->get();
```

How can i get records in relationship part on basis of account_id and service_id both.
Currently records are display in relationship of completedSericeRest have all the records who account_id is match with AccountService table.

When that relation happen then check both service_id and account_id from completed service not only account_id.

Below relationship in model.

```
 public function completedServiceRest() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\CompletedService', 'account_id', 'account_id');
}
```

[image]

currently get all the records of the account_id matched not on basis of both parameters service_id and account_id affect only account_id.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier with another structure, an example of your table "Account Service" (of course, completed will be 0 by default) :

```
id | service_id | account_id | completed |
------------------------------------------
1 |      1      |    8181    |     0     |
2 |      2      |    8181    |     1     |
```

Your main relation would be :

```
public function accountedServices() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\AccountService', 'account_id', 'account_id');
}
```

And to check your completed services :

```
public function completedServiceRest() 
{
    return $services->accountedServices()->where('completed', 1)->get();
}
```

Comment: No i can't modify my table structure because there is lots of other field are there not only completed or not by 0,1. so this will not work. TX